# mysql query joins query2

Tags: mysql, database

I have the following MYSQL query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM quizquestions 
INNER JOIN option2 ON quizquestions.question_id=option2.question_id 
WHERE quizquestions.quiz_id=13
```

Basically, i have two tables, one table with questions, and another table storing 4 options to every question. So for example, the quizquestions table will be the following:

```
Question_id (Primary Key), quiz_id(to link it to the quiz), question

  61                       13                               1+2
```

Then the options table would be like the following:

```
Option id (Primary Key), Question_id(To link it to the correct question), optionvalue

      181                61                                               3
```

Currently, im using a loop to display both the question and the options, however, whenever i use the INNER JOIN query as shown above, i get the following:

```
question_id    quiz_id    question    optionid    question_id    optionvalue

     61            13       1+2        181         61           1
     61            13       1+2        182         61           2
     61            13       1+2        183         61           3
     61            13       1+2        184         61           4
```

However, i would like it to display like this:

```
Question_id    Quiz_ID     question   optionvalue    optionvalue    optionvalue    optionvalue

    61          13          1+2       1               2            3               4
```

This is so that i wont have duplicates of question_id/quiz_id as seen in the first column.

Can this be achieved?

Comment: The loop seems like a sensible solution. I guess you could try `group_concat` and then use php `explode` function. But that's kind of hacky solution. If you have answers that are sentences, you'd have to pick a good separator as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT q.Question_id as questionId, q.Quiz_ID as quizId, q.question as question, GROUP_CONCAT(op.optionvalue SEPARATOR ' ') as options
FROM quizquestions q INNER JOIN option2 op ON q.question_id=op.question_id WHERE q.quiz_id=13
GROUP BY q.Question_id
```

OR

```
    SELECT q.Question_id as questionId, q.Quiz_ID as quizId, q.question as question, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(op.optionvalue), ',', 1), ',', -1) AS option1,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(op.optionvalue), ',', 2), ',', -1) AS option2,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(op.optionvalue), ',', 3), ',', -1) AS option3,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(op.optionvalue), ',', 4), ',', -1) AS option4
    FROM quizquestions q INNER JOIN option2 op ON q.question_id=op.question_id WHERE q.quiz_id=13
    GROUP BY q.Question_id
```

Try this.

Comment: hi there, this worked very well for me, and it does concats the options separated by a space, do i then explode out the options one by one? Thanks!

Comment: You can use split function and use it separately.

Comment: if query is working for you, you should mark the answer as accepted so that other can see it and use this answer :)

Comment: another question is what if lets say the options were strings, would it work as well?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67835/discussion-between-hacker-and-vishal-zanzrukia).